# Avoid widget lock for setState in the onPress button?

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

I want to implement simple login/logout system with firebase. I have successfully implemented the login/logout system. When login the user will directed to Home Screen and after logout the user will be directed to Login Screen (Using RootScreen to handle going to Home or Login). Then I add new page SettingScreen and move logout process to setting page. So, the process is user Login -> Homepage (open drawer) -> Setting.  However after doing this, the logout process become error in Setting Screen and got this message

> "another exception: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget
>   tree was locked"

Strangely, there is no problem with the Setting Screen code if I directly doing login/logout process from HomePage to Setting Screen.

Codes (RootScreen & SettingScreen):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';
import 'home_screen.dart';
import 'setting_screen.dart';
import '../utilities/auth.dart';

class RootScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  RootScreen({this.auth});
  final BaseAuth auth;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new RootState();
}

enum AuthStatus { notSignedIn, signedIn }

class RootState extends State<RootScreen> {
  AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId) {
      setState(() {
        authStatus =
            userId == null ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
      });
    });
  }

  void signedIn() {
    setState(() {
      authStatus = AuthStatus.signedIn;
    });
  }

  void signedOut() {
    setState(() {
      authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return new LoginScreen(auth: widget.auth, onSignedIn: signedIn);
      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        return new HomeScreen(auth: widget.auth, onSignedOut: signedOut);
    }
  }
}

2. Setting Screen & State:

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../utilities/auth.dart';

class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  SettingScreen({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;
  final String title = "Setting";

  @override
  SettingState createState() => SettingState();
}

class SettingState extends State<SettingScreen> {

  void signOut() async {
    setState(() {
      try {
        widget.auth.signOut();
        widget.onSignedOut();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Settings'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: Text('Logout',
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: signOut,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
          child: new Center(
        child: new Text('Settings', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

HomeScreen:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});
  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  @override
  HomeState createState() => HomeState();

  void signOut() async {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      onSignedOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
//.. Inside the HomeState -> ListTile to Setting Menu
ListTile(
        title:
            Text('Pengaturan', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        onTap: () {
          // Update the state of the app
          // ...
          // Then close the drawer
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SettingScreen(
                    auth: widget.auth, onSignedOut: widget.onSignedOut)),
          );
        },
      ),
//..
```

How to avoid this setState & widget lock exception for this case?

Comment: Try to pop the drawer before updating the state

Comment: Thank you, Add two Navigator.pop(context) (first before Navigator.push and the second one in signOut method) solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you based on aziza comment, I solve the problem by add two Navigator.pop(context) the first one in drawer before go into other menu to avoid widget lock and the second one in sign out method so come back to RootScreen.

Home State Drawer:

```
//.. Inside the HomeState -> ListTile to Setting Menu
ListTile(
        title:
            Text('Pengaturan', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        onTap: () {
          // ...
          // Add this
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SettingScreen(
                    auth: widget.auth, onSignedOut: widget.onSignedOut)),
          );
        },
      ),
//..
```

Sign Out method in Setting Screen:

```
void signOut() async {
    setState(() {
      try {
        widget.auth.signOut();
        widget.onSignedOut();
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to use WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {}

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     widget.auth.currentUser().then((userId) {
       setState(() {
         authStatus =
             userId == null ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
       });
     });    
   });
   
}
```